# How to fix install_name_tool: can't open file in xcode 10.2

Tags: xcode, macos, version

This is my first post, so hopefully, I followed the rules correctly...

> install_name_tool: can't open file: /Users/App/Desktop/myApp/DerivedData/MyApp/Build/Products/Debug/Test.app/Contents/Frameworks/mylib.dylib (No such file or directory)

This started with Version 10.2 (10E125). Prior to this version, the install_name tool worked just fine. From what I am seeing is that the Copy Script under Build Phases is executing before the Xcode actually copies the dylibs to the @executable_path/../Frameworks/mylib.dylib" "${APP_FILENAME}".

I add the dylibs to Xcode as follows(letting Xcode handle all copying):
1. Linked Frameworks and Libraries then add
2. Embedded Binaries 
3. Added the actual code to relink to Build Phases => Run Script:

> install_name_tool -change "${LIB_PATH}/libtest.dylib" "@executable_path/../Frameworks/libtest.dylib" "${APP_FILENAME}"
>   install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libtest.dylib "${FRAMEWORK_PATH}/mylib.dylib"```

Following several suggestions I have:
1. Used a sleep statement in the Copy Script, but it just pauses Xcode from running and still the same issue.
2. Used an external script, same issue.
3. Added to post, the same issue.

I am thinking its something simple and I cannot put my finger on it.

> install_name_tool -change "${LIB_PATH}/libtest.dylib" "@executable_path/../Frameworks/libtest.dylib" "${APP_FILENAME}"
>   install_name_tool -id @executable_path/../Frameworks/libtest.dylib "${FRAMEWORK_PATH}/mylib.dylib"

I am trying to rename the dylibs so they point to @executable_path/../Frameworks/, from the original location of /usr/local/opt/

Comment: Are you only getting that one error message?  Any reason that file doesnt exist?

Comment: The dylibs copy just fine, the issue is, Xcode fires the scripts in scheme->edit Scheme->post or New Run Script Phase prior to the dylib copy process finishing. I can see in the log where the script fires, then Xcode copies the dylibs over. I have tried external script, sleep statements in scripts(Xcode just waits then proceeds as usual), also changed Xcode to legacy with no success. I am letting Xcode handle the entire process. I guess I will have to handle the copy dylibs myself in the New Script Phase then run the install_tool.

Answer (score 0):

I have **resolved** the error.
In my case i have removed **Run Script** from the **Build Phase** in XCode.